# Datepicker not visible on popupPanel

Tags: java, gwt

I want to add a dateBox on a popupanel like dialogBox. But here datepicker popups behind popupPanel and not visible on the top of it.

```
final DialogBox box = new DialogBox();
box.setGlassEnabled(true);
box.setStyleName("popupBox");
box.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(25);
box.setWidget(vPnl);
box.show();
box.center();
box.setAnimationEnabled(true);
```

here i have one verticalPanel which contains flexTable having some number of tabs. For the worikng of flextable on popup i have set zIndex to 25. I want to add datebox in flextable.
Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with **z-index** which you defined. because of datebox popup z-index is less then your `box` mean dialog box's z-index, it shows behind popup panel. **why do you need to set z-index here to show flex table on popup?** it's not mandatory. show more code.

If you put anything inside popup, it show front of popup without use of z-index.
Check your `popupBox` style, I think that this style might also have some z-index code.

Comment: no.. popupBox style dont have zIndex defined. It shows flextable on top without zzIndex but problem is with tabs.I have n number of tabs in flex table and if i remove zIndex , those tabs become unclickable.

Comment: ok, can you show your code. because I want to see why tabs become unclickable? because I think as you are trying to solve this problem using z-index. but this will force to assign z-index for all elements which you will going to use inside dialog box or might other feature.

Comment: I think Bhumika is right. I have never had to set any z-index in my application and have never had any problems with my popups even very complex ones.

Comment: even I agree.. I have tried with fresh new test code and its working fine there. May be some other problem is there in my original application code which is still unresolved. It is working only when i set zIndex,otherwise tabs become unclickable.I will check it out.